# Can't query join on views from two different databases in Synapse Serverless SQL pool

Tags: azure-synapse

I have two databases in Synapse Analytics Serverless pool. User is created in both databases, has select permission and granted reference to database scoped credentials. When I try to query join on two views from two different databases I receive an error:

`The server principal "user" is not able to access the database "databasename" under the current security context.`

Views are build over external data from blob storage. When I query views from it's database context everything work clear.

I was removing and recreating login and users, but it didn't help. I suspect that user from database on which I execute the query needs an access to the second database and to it's scoped credentials to access data from blob.

Is anyone who experienced same issue in the past? Is there any way to fix it or does the Synapse Serverless doesn't support such a solution?

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/cross-database-query-in-azure-sql-database/ba-p/369126

Comment: I see it is dedicated to azure sql database, does it work with Synapse Serverless too?

Comment: I am trying on it will update the solution.

Comment: Hey can you check this 
https://www.serverlesssql.com/elastic-queries-with-azure-sql-database-and-serverless-sql-pools/#:~:text=It%20can%20be%20done%20successfully,the%20Serverless%20SQL%20Pools%20engine.

if this help

Comment: I am trying at my end too.

Answer (score 0):

The error message **"The server principal 'user' is not able to access the database 'databasename' under the current security context"** indicates a permissions issue.

You can try the below steps to resolve the issue:

**Step 1:** create a connection to the underlying data lake storage account in Azure.

**Step 2:** creates a schema to logically store the View definition in,
create a scoped credential which uses Active Directory to authenticate with the Azure Storage account, and finally sets the collation of the database to support `UTF-8` data.

```
CREATE DATABASE sqllogicaldw;
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ExternalDataSourceDataLake
    WITH (
        LOCATION   = 'https://<storage account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/datalakehouse'
        );
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT SynapseParquetFormat
WITH (
        FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET
     );
CREATE SCHEMA LDW authorization dbo;
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Diliprajnarayan@1';
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SynapseUserIdentity
WITH IDENTITY = 'User Identity';
ALTER DATABASE sqllogicaldw COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8;
```

[image]

In the context of our setup using **"User Identity"** in the database scoped credential, it's essential to ensure that the user account utilized in Synapse Studio is granted access in the Azure Storage Access Control (IAM) with the role of Storage Blob Data Contributor.

This access is necessary for both reading and writing data to the storage account, which is crucial for the tasks outlined in parts two and three of this blog series.
This step ensures that the user has the required permissions for interacting with the storage account in both read and write operations.

**Alternative Azure Storage Authentication:**

- In the SQL code provided earlier, we utilized the **"User Identity"** option to enable pass-through authentication. However, for enhanced query performance, it's recommended to explore the SAS token authentication option. It's advisable to experiment with different options to determine the most effective approach for your specific environment.

The following code demonstrates how to create a database-scoped credential and another data source utilizing SAS token authentication.

You have the flexibility to create multiple database-scoped credentials and data sources, allowing you to compare the performance of both "User Identity" and "SAS" authentication methods.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [SasToken]
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
     SECRET = '<SAS TOKEN>';
GO
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE ExternalDataSourceDataLakeSAS
WITH (    LOCATION   = 'https://<Storage accont name >.dfs.core.windows.net/datalakehouse',
          CREDENTIAL = SasToken
)
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Creating a Logical Data Warehouse with Synapse Serverless](https://www.datahai.co.uk/logical-data-warehouse/creating-a-logical-data-warehouse-in-serverless-sql-part-1-setting-up/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you use Microsoft Entra Id for authentication then the following steps might help:

1. Open SSMS and connect to your Synapse workspace.
2. Execute the following query on master DB. Replace [User/Usergroup].

> ```
> USE MASTER;
> CREATE LOGIN [User/Usergroup] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
> ```